# Is this shuffle algorithm right?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

The following is the shuffle algorithm I implemented in ruby:

```
def shuffle03!(arr)
    len = arr.length
    for i in 0..len-1
        index1 = Random.rand(0..len-1)
        index2 = Random.rand(0..len-1)
        arr[index1], arr[index2] = arr[index2], arr[index1]
    end
end
```

I tested this algorithm by  reckoning:

```
class ShuffleTest
    def initialize(seed)
        len = seed.length
        @count = {}
        for i in 0..len-1
            @count[seed[i]] = Array.new(len, 0)
        end
    end
    def test(arr)
        for i in 0...arr.length
            @count[arr[i]][i] += 1
        end
    end
    def show_count
        return @count
    end
end


def shuffle03!(arr)
    len = arr.length
    for i in 0..len-1
        index1 = Random.rand(0..len-1)
        index2 = Random.rand(0..len-1)
        arr[index1], arr[index2] = arr[index2], arr[index1]
    end
end


arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

st = ShuffleTest.new(arr)

for x in 0..100_0000
    shuffle03!(arr)
    st.test(arr)
end

st.show_count.each do |k, v|
    puts k
    p v
end
```

the result was :

```
a
[250418, 249105, 249553, 250925]
b
[249372, 250373, 250785, 249471]
c
[250519, 250097, 249369, 250016]
d
[249692, 250426, 250294, 249589]
```

It semms to be correct. However, I donnot know **how to prove it with mathematical statistics.** So I'm not sure it is correct.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on another site: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: why are you randomly generating 2 indices? (so, probably not correct) see the wiki article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: @MitchWheat: I believe that codereview.stackexchange.com expects questions to contain correct, working code. (The answers then suggest readability/design/performance/etc. improvements.) This code is not correct, so I believe it would not be on-topic there.

Comment: I amended by answer to provide a proof that your algorithm does not produce a random reordering of a given sequence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not right.

Imagine that you have a four-element list, [A,B,C,D]. Observe that:

- There are 4! = 24 possible permutations. For this to be a correct shuffling algorithm, each of these permutations needs to be equally likely.
- You are generating 4×2 = 8 random integers, each in the range 0–3, for a total of 4<sup>8</sup> = 65,536 possible sequences of random numbers. Each of these sequences is equally likely.
- 65,536 is not divisible by 24, so there is no way that your algorithm can map the 65,536 possible random-number sequences to permutations in a way that assigns an equal number of random-number sequences (and hence an equal probability) to each permutation.

---

To see this in a test, you can create a variant of your `shuffle03!` that, instead of using a random-generator, takes a list of eight indices, and uses those. (`shuffle03!` could then be implemented by generating eight random indices and then calling this variant as a helper-function.) Your test would then iterate over all 4096 possible sequences, and for each one, create a four-element list [A,B,C,D] and then call the variant method to see the resulting permutation. The test can keep count of how often each permutation appears, and use this to find which permutations appear more times than others. What you'll find is:

```
 Permutation    # of Occurrences
-------------  ------------------
 A B C D                    4480
 A B D C                    3072
 A C B D                    3072
 A C D B                    2880
 A D B C                    2880
 A D C B                    3072
 B A C D                    3072
 B A D C                    2432
 B C A D                    2880
 B C D A                    2048
 B D A C                    2048
 B D C A                    2880
 C A B D                    2880
 C A D B                    2048
 C B A D                    3072
 C B D A                    2880
 C D A B                    2432
 C D B A                    2048
 D A B C                    2048
 D A C B                    2880
 D B A C                    2880
 D B C A                    3072
 D C A B                    2048
 D C B A                    2432
```

As you can see, elements tend to end up in the same order they started; for example, `A B C D` is the most common permutation. We can pull out one aspect of this by seeing, for each pair of elements, how often they end up in the same order vs. the opposite order. We find:

```
 Elements    Same Order    Opposite Order
----------  ------------  ----------------
 A and B          33792             31744
 A and C          34816             30720
 A and D          35840             29696
 B and C          33792             31744
 B and D          34816             30720
 C and D          33792             31744
```

So some pairs are more likely than others to end up in the opposite order, but each pair is more likely to end up in the same order than to end up in the opposite order.

You can reduce the imbalance by performing more passes, but since no power of 8 is divisible by 24, it will never be possible to make all permutations equally likely.

---

By the way, if your actual goal here is a good shuffle algorithm (rather than just the learning experience of figuring one out for yourself), then you should use a [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Of course, since you're using Ruby, you can bypass the whole issue by just using `Array.shuffle!`, which performs the Fisher–Yates shuffle for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest a Ruby-way of achieving your objective.

Evidently, you cannot use [Array#shuffle](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) but (thankfully!) can use [Kernel#rand](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-rand). (I assume you can't use [Array#sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-sample) either, as: `arr.sample(arr.size)` has the same effect as `arr.shuffle`.)

There are many ways to implement `shuffle` that are statistically valid (on the assumption that `rand(n)` produces truly random numbers between `0` and `n-1`, which of course is not possible, but that's a reasonable assumption).  Here's one way:

```
class Array
  def shuffle
    arr = self.dup
    map { arr.delete_at(rand(arr.size)) }
  end
end
```

Let's try it with:

```
arr = [4,:a,5,6,'b',7,8]

arr.shuffle #=> [6,   8, "b", 5,   4, :a,   7]
arr.shuffle #=> [5,  :a,   8, 4, "b",  7,   6]
arr.shuffle #=> [6,   8,   5, 7, "b", :a,   4]
arr.shuffle #=> [6,   4,   7, 8,   5, :a, "b"]
arr.shuffle #=> [:a,  4, "b", 5,   7,  8,   6]
arr.shuffle #=> ["b", 4,   7, 8,  :a,  6,   5]
```

Comment: You define `Array#sample`, but you call `Array#shuffle` in your example. Otherwise, I like the approach you use with map and delete_at. Clever. +1

Comment: Thanks, @Daniël. I fixed it, and also added a proof that the OP's algorithm does not produce random permutations of the array. This is a little amusing. I meant for the method to be `shuffle`, but wrote `sample`, and then tested with (Ruby's) `shuffle`. Of course it worked! Fortunately, I seem to have written the method correctly, except for the name.

Comment: Thanks, @ruakh. Yes, of course. I'll delete that, but I'd still like to see a solid mathematical proof for arrays of arbitrary size.

Comment: @ruakh, sorry, I meant I'd still like to see a rigorous proof that, for arrays of arbitrary size, the OP's algorithm does not produce random sequences.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Can you formalize the statement that you'd like to see a proof of? Normally a claim is considered disproved if a single counterexample is found, so I think we've already rigorously disproved the claim that "given an array of arbitrary length, the OP's algorithm produces a random shuffling of it, with all permutations being equally likely". We cannot disprove the weaker claim that "given an array of arbitrary length, the OP's algorithm produces a random shuffling of it, with all permutations being possible", because that weaker claim is in fact true.

Comment: @ruahk, you are right, again. Since you've provided the counter-example, that is sufficient.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Understood. For what it's worth, my same argument for [A, B, C, D] applies to any array of 3 or more elements, provided that all elements are distinct. (If n >= 3, then for n ^ 2n to be divisible by n!, n would have to be a multiple of every prime that is less than n. But that's impossible, because then n-1 could not be a multiple of *any* prime less than n: it would have to be some sort of magical superprime that's not even divisible by itself.)